# Laravel validation require if the user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

So let's say I've got a custom request called `CreateReviewRequest`.

In this request, I've got this method:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      => 'required_if(auth->logged)',
        'comments'  => 'required|max:255',
        'stars'     => 'required|min:1|max:5',
    ];
}
```

As you can see in the `name` key, I want from the client to be required to fill the `name` field if he's not logged in.

So my question is, how can I exactly require my client to fill the `name` when he's a guest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `check()` method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      => auth()->check() ? 'required' : '',
        'comments'  => 'required|max:255',
        'stars'     => 'required|min:1|max:5',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Well that's the answer that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Member only:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

     'email' => auth()->check() ? '' : 'required|min:5|max:60|email',

]);
```

**Guest only:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

     'user_id' => auth()->check() ? 'required|integer|min:1' : '',

]);
```

**Both:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

     'message' => 'required|min:10|max:1000'

]);
```

**Combined:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

     'email' => auth()->check() ? '' : 'required|min:5|max:60|email',
     'user_id' => auth()->check() ? 'required|integer|min:1' : '',
     'message' => 'required|min:10|max:1000'

]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you make a simple check?

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return [
            'comments'  => 'required|max:255',
            'stars'     => 'required|min:1|max:5',
        ];
    }

    return [
        'name'      => 'required',
        'comments'  => 'required|max:255',
        'stars'     => 'required|min:1|max:5',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Or attach an auth middleware route to the controller method.

Comment: Attaching an auth middleware would not allow a guest to access the route am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. It wouldn't solve OPs issue. I misunderstood at first.

Comment: @El_Matella I can achieve that goal with fewer lines by declaring a `$rules` var. I was just hoping that there's a custom role validation for that.

Comment: A more elegant solution wil be to make a variable storing the array, like:
`$rules = []; if (auth()->check()) $rules['name'] = 'required'; return $rules;`